# Не могу вывести acf group поля

Tags: wordpress, acf

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

мой код

```
 <?php if( have_rows('express_one_block') ): //parent group field
while( have_rows('express_one_block') ): the_row();
// vars
   $name = get_sub_field('one_block_icon');
   $birth = get_sub_field('one_block_title');
   $phone = get_sub_field('one_block_text');
?>
        <div class="xpress-item xpress-one">
            <img data-wow-delay="0.2s" data-wow-duration="1s" class="wow fadeInDown" src="<?php echo $name ?>" alt="">
            <h3><?php echo $birth ?></h3>
            <p><?php echo $phone ?></p>
        </div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
```

что не так? просто не выводится ничего

Answer (score 0):

Я вывожу поля через отдельную страницу настроек, поэтому нужно вот так выводить:

```
<?php if( have_rows('express_one_block', 'option') ): //parent group field
```